# Problems with getting untrunc to find files

Tags: video

I've been trying to use the tool "untrunc", installed via SNAP, and when trying to figure out the issue I found a similar post here (which did not address it). Here's the issue:

```
% untrunc-anthwlock fixed.mp4 C0011.MP4
Info: version 'v308-d72ec32' using ffmpeg 'd72ec32'
Info: reading fixed.mp4
Could not open file 'fixed.mp4': No such file or directory
% michaelp-anthwlock-untrunc.untrunc fixed.mp4 C0011.MP4
Info: version '77b30ac' using ffmpeg '3.3.9'
Info: reading fixed.mp4
Could not open file: fixed.mp4
% ls -l
total 26249241
-rwxrwxrwx 1 alexq  alexq   18122539008 Sep 26  2015 C0011.MP4
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root   root      427411639 Sep  3 19:30 fixed.mp4
```

Comment: I suspect this is an issue with the snap containment model - see for example [snap install -> Could not open file #73](https://github.com/anthwlock/untrunc/issues/73). What does `snap connections untrunc` report?

Comment: This seems to have helped a lot thanks! It's still a bit wonky but I did get it to finally run.